# Can't I display symbol € into pdf?

Tags: encoding, pdf-generation, symbols, euro

I am using pdftk.exe to fill a pdf template and i need fill input form with € symbol.

The problem is that when it views the pdf, not displaying the € symbol and It replace by a special symbol (¤).

It could be by the encoding, but i don't know how solve it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: So, what have you done?

Comment: I have tried test with some fonts, but it doesn't work

Comment: Also, I have tested with pdf templates done with adobe acrobat reader and Foxit PhatomPDF.

Comment: I'm working with ruby, but this for question has not found fix